# issues with chained hash tables

Tags: c, hash, struct, chained

I'm having major trouble figuring out how to do this correctly. The output was until shortly riddles with errors. I managed to fix most of them but I'm still left with two, and likely a bunch of logic errors.

I also have trouble with my hash algorithm, so I have replaced it with simple temp code. The instructions for the correct one are:

> The hash function to be used is h(k) = m(k · A mod 1) where
>   A = (√5 − 1)/2 and k · A mod 1 returns the fractional part of k · A.

I assume I've not implemented it properly.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define TABLE_SIZE 8

typedef struct stItem item;
struct stItem {
    int key;
    item *next;
};

void init(item * H[]) {

    int i = 0;
    for (i; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++)
        H[i] = NULL;
}

int h(int k) {

    // this does not work at all, currently using testcode

    /*
    int m = TABLE_SIZE;
    int A = ( sqrt(5.0) - 1) / 2;

    return m * (k * A % 1);
    */

    return k % TABLE_SIZE;
}

void insert(int key, item * H[]) {

    int keyHashed = h(key);

    if (H[keyHashed] == NULL) {

        item * temp = malloc(sizeof(item));
        temp->key = key;
        temp->next = NULL;

        H[keyHashed] = temp;

        free(temp);
    }

    else {

        item * temp = malloc(sizeof(item));
        temp->next = H[keyHashed]->next;

        while (temp != NULL) {
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        temp->key = key;
        temp->next = NULL;
    }
}

int search(int key, item * H[]) {

        int keyHashed = h(key);

        if (H[keyHashed] == NULL)
            return -1;

        else if (H[keyHashed]->key != key) {

            item * temp = malloc(sizeof(item));
            temp->next = H[keyHashed]->next;

            while (temp->key != key && temp != NULL)
                temp = temp->next;

            if (temp->key == key) {
                free(temp);
                return keyHashed;
            }

            else {
                free(temp);
                return -1;
            }
        }

        else
            return keyHashed;
}

void printHash(item * H[]) {

    printf("Table size: %d", TABLE_SIZE);

    int i = 0;

    for (i; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++) {

        if (H[i] != NULL) {
            printf("i: %d          key: %d",i,H[i]->key);

            if (H[i]->next != NULL) {

                item * temp = malloc(sizeof(item));
                temp->next = H[i]->next;

                while (temp != NULL) {
                    printf(" -> %d", temp->key);
                }

                printf("\n");
            }

            else
                printf("\n");
        }
    }
}

void test() {

    // a)
    int array[7] = {111,10112,1113,5568,63,1342,21231};

    item *h[TABLE_SIZE];
    init(h);

    int i = 0;
    for (i; i < 7; i++)
        insert(array[i], h);


    // b)

    printHash(h);


    // c)

    printf("Search result for 1: %d", search(1, h));
    printf("Search result for 10112: %d", search(10112, h));
    printf("Search result for 1113: %d", search(1113, h));
    printf("Search result for 5568: %d", search(5568, h));
    printf("Search result for 337: %d", search(337, h));
}

int main() {
    test();
}
```

EDIT: Thanks to user3386109's fix the code now compiles with no errors but what happens is that the command prompt just pops up with nothing displayed in it and nothing happening at all. It doesn't close either. Not even after several minutes of waiting.

EDIT2: After some more testing it looks to be hanging up on the insert-function. Nothing after the for-loop in `test()` is executed.

If I add this `printf("init done %d", h[1]);` to just after the `init()` in the test function, I get "init done 0" instead of "init done NULL", might that be one of the issues?

Comment: `struct item *` should be `struct listADT *` when declaring the `next` member. There is no `struct item`.

Comment: I just updated the original post this minute with the latest code and output (none). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure definition is malformed. I would suggest the following

```
typedef struct stItem item; 
struct stItem {
    int key;
    item *next;
};
```

Comment: Is this a readability issue? Because I've used this kind of struct def before and not noticed any problems caused by it. I don't mind changing it of course but does this actually cause problems? EDIT: Changed it and I don't have any error messages anymore, interestingly. The command prompt window seems to do nothing at all though - it pops up and nothing is appearing in it.

Comment: You had a structure called `struct listADT` and a type called `item`. So the line `struct item *next` confused the compiler, since there was no such thing as `struct item`.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have an idea as to what could be the cause of the rest of my problems? I have updated the post with some more information regarding it.

Comment: It's best to start a new question, since this question (before the edits) seemed to be about the compiler errors.